# Zerocoin vs. Zerocash ? are they the same ? Or two different protocols?

Tags: privacy, confidential-transactions, zero-knowledge, zerocoin

what is the main difference between **Zerocoin** vs. **Zerocash** ?  are they the same ? Or two different protocols ? If they are two different protocols, what are similarities ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zerocoin is a proposed extension on Bitcoin to make Bitcoin more private. Zerocoin only hides the origin of a payment, the destination and amounts are still public.

Zerocash is a further extension of the zerocoin protocol which hides the destination and amounts. Zerocash transactions are more compact than zerocoin transactions.

Zcash is an implementation of the zerocash protocol onto a new altcoin. Both Zerocoin and Zerocash were intended for extensions to Bitcoin (they would require a fork). However zcash is just an altcoin (it began as a software fork of Bitcoin) with the zerocash protocol on top.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean `Zcash` and `Bitcoin` use the same blockchain? (Since Zcash is an independent coin); Thanks

Comment: No, they use separate blockchains. Zcash is an altcoin which implements the Zerocash protocol.

Comment: A bit off-topic: for anonymity features of ZCash, see also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/64281/36884